# Middleware for "guest" type user, using Dingo API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, dingo-api

My `User` model may be *anonymous* (eg. no e-mail registered, `$user->isAnonymous()`). By using the `api.auth` middleware both *anonymous* and fully registered users can access a given route. Now I want to restrict a route, so that *anonymous* users can not access it.

(Important to notice that "*anonymous* users" are still authenticated, *anonymous* **does not** refer to unauthenticated)

The question is, where should I place this logic to best conform with the Dingo package? Am I looking at making my own middleware, extending Dingo, or maybe making a custom provider for Dingo?

**Bonus question:** I think the best result would have one middleware (eg. `api.auth`) only authorize those users that are *not anonymous*, and the second middleware (eg. `auth.all`) authorize *both anonymous* and *non-anonymous* users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for nested middlewares like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get(...); //all authenticated users can see this

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'known'], function() {
        //assuming the middleware name is 'known' in kernel.php
        Route::get(....); //Only known users (non-anonymous) will get in here
    });
});
```

For the middleware you could do

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()){
        if(!Auth::user()->email) {
            return redirect('/'); //no email. kick them out!
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Or anything similar.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely the simplest approach to the problem, and simple is often the way to go. I will just leave it out there for the rest of the day to see if anyone has a better idea.